# Parameter has a function

Tags: powershell

In Powershell can I pass a function as a  param of a function?

```
Test (!((Get-SPSolution $name).Deployed))

Function Test {
    param ($extFunc)

    do { Start-Sleep -Seconds 30 } while ($extFunc)
}
```

Comment: look at using scriptblocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that without a problem. One thing though, you need to call the test function AFTER it has been declared, otherwise you'll get an error (The term 'Test' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet).

Here's an example that demonstrate it, you should see messages written to the console every second.

```
function Test-SPSolution
{
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{Deployed=$false}
}

Function Test {
    param ($extFunc)

    do { 
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        Write-Host "extFunc = $extFunc"
    } while ($extFunc)
}

Test (!(Test-SPSolution foo).Deployed)
```

Comment: I think the OP wasn't in execution order ;)

Comment: Regardless, he should be able to call the function the way he's trying to, there's no need to cast it to string and evaluate it. Agree?

Comment: um.. could you add what you mean in your answer, because I can't figure out how can it work without be a string type or a sciptblock. Thank you

Comment: Ok, can you explain why in this case doesn't work? Function Test {param ($extFunc) do { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 Write-Host "extFunc = $extFunc - $((get-date).second)"} while ($extFunc)} calling Test (((Get-date).second -ne 30))

Comment: The do/while loop not end when (get-date).second is equal to 30

Comment: it shouldn't stop. You call the function once only. If at the time the function called the second wasn't 30 ($extFunc will set to $false) it will keep on going ($extFunc is $true).

Comment: no problem, then, I have not understood the meaning of the question in OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can try  like this:

```
Test "(!((Get-SPSolution $name).Deployed))"

Function Test {
    param ($extFunc)

    do { Start-Sleep -Seconds 30 } while ((iex $extFunc))
}
```

Pass a `[string]` to your `Test` function and use `invoke-expression` cmdlet